# NetcatSource : Client sent exceeding the maximum length

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, netcat, flume-ng

Hello everybody and thanks in advance for taking time reading this :)
I'm trying to send a JSON object in my Hadoop cluster for process it with Spark, this JSON is about 15KB. I set my flume agent this way :

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = netcat
a1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.r1.port = 41400
a1.sources.r1.max-line-length = 512000
a1.sources.r1.eventSize = 512000
#a1.sources.deserializer.maxLineLength = 512000

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /hadoop/hdfs/data
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = CDR
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.callTimeout = 15000
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollCount = 226
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.batchSize = 226

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = file
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 512000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity =512000 

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Except that , I have a perl's script which send the JSON Object trough a socket at the port indicated, but when I start the flume agent I get this message :

```
 WARN source.NetcatSource: Client sent event exceeding the maximum length
```

What I don't understand is that I set the max-line-length of my event at 512000 Bytes, which is bigger than 15 KB, does anybody can help me ?
Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You could verify that your json (on your perl script) ends with a newline (EOL) character.

Cf.  documentation : https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#netcat-source